# Passing a 2d array from controller to model in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, mysql, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have a form that gets the access type name (textbox), description (textbox) and its corresponding functions (the checked checkboxes). The access type name and description are saved in a table and there is another table for the access type id and functions.

```
access_type_id   |   function_id
      1          |        1
      1          |        2
```

So far, I have an array of checked checkboxes that is being passed to the controller through ajax. The array looks like [1, 2] where 1 and 2 are the ids of the checked checkboxes.

```
$('#thisForm').on('submit', function() {
    var functionArray = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e, i) {
        return +e.value;
    });

    var string = $.ajax({
            url: 'checkFields',
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'acfFunctions': functionArray}
    });
});
```

In the controller I tried to create an array of arrays but when I pass this to the model, errors occur. How can I fix these problems. Thank you in advance.

> JSON.parse: unexpected character
>
> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

```
public function checkFields() {
    $data= array(
        'access_type_name' => trim(ucwords($this->input->post('accessName'))),
        'access_type_description' => trim(ucwords($this->input->post('accessDescription')))
    );

    $id = $this->home_model->saveAccessType($data); 
    //This is working. It really returns the id.
    $acfFunctions = $this->input->post('acfFunctions');

    $i=0;
    $data2 = array();
    for($i; $i<count($acfFunctions); $i++){
        $data2[$i]=array(
            $data2['access_type_id'] = $id, 
            $data2['function_id'] = $acfFunctions[$i]
        );
    }

    $this->home_model->saveAccessTypeFunction($data2);
    redirect('home/setPermissions');
}
```

Here's the model

```
public function saveAccessTypeFunction($data){
    $result=$this->db->insert_batch('access_type_function',$data);
    if($result){
        return $data;   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code as below. You have to mention the field name in data array to insert into db table.

> for($i; $i < count($acfFunctions); $i++)
>
> {
>
> ```
>     $data2[$i]=array(
>         'access_type_id' => $id, // access_type_id is table field name
>         'function_id' => $acfFunctions[$i]
>     );
> }
> ```

For reference: [CI Tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)